# How to get ABRecordRef from ABRecordID?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I have accessed the address book and success fully extracted the records and necessary info from it. I have also extracted **recordid**.
My problem is how to use this recordid to extract record later.
The code which I am using is:

```
ABRecordID recordId;
ABAddressBookRef _addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate ();
NSArray* allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBookRef);

for (id record in allPeople) {
    recordId = ABRecordGetRecordID(record);

    //i am saving each one  how to use them later to extract particular record
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously, the results of `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` is an array of `ABPersonRef`, which you then individually use to get your `ABRecordID`. If at some later point, you want to take your `recordId` to retrieve the `ABPersonRef`, you use [`ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID).