# how to set image from UIImage in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am fetching an image from contact and storing it like:

```
NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
UIImage  *img = [UIImage imageWithData:contactImageData];
NSLog(@"%@",img); //returns like '<UIImage: 0x7fc740460260>'

[contactInfoDict setObject:img forKey:@"image"]; //contactInfoDict is a NSDictionary
```

Now again I'm setting the image like:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"])];
cell.profileImg.image = image;
```

But nothing happening. there is no image at all. What I did wrong?

**Update**

I also tried:

```
NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
[contactInfoDict setObject:contactImageData forKey:@"image"];
```

fetching it like:

```
 NSString *str = [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];
 NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 cell.profileImg.image = image;
```

But not working. After setting NSData to image image returns nil.

Comment: Try debugging.  Is `img` a valid object?  Are `image`, `cell`, and `cell.profileImg`?

Comment: Try using Type cast **UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"]**;   Also you can get the direct image by **img = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person)];**

Comment: Yes all are valid objects!

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota: not working!!! crashed.

Comment: What do you see if you put `NSLog(@"profileImg: %@", [cell.profileImg class]);` just before the `image` assignment?

Comment: //  **contactInfoDict** is a NSDictionary , can you Make it **NSMutableDictionary** ?

Comment: Can you try my answer & let me know?

Comment: @PhillipMills: it returns -> `profileImg: UIImageView`

Comment: @PhillipMills: Can you help with the second option? I just updated the question.

Comment: Hi , i have updated my answer, you can check it..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `check` `person` has `image`. Now use `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat`

```
if (ABPersonHasImageData(yourPersonObject)) 
{
   //person has image
   //ARC need to take ownership of the Core Foundation object . Use CFBridgingRelease
   //Your mistake is here where i have changed
   NSData *imgData = CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(yourPersonObject, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail));

   if(imgData)
   {
      UIImage  *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
      if(img)
      {
         [contactInfoDict setObject:img forKey:@"image"];
      }
   }
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"no image");
}
```

Comment: Ok then How do I fetch the image and set it to a view??

Comment: Check my answer completely.

Comment: Ok, I'm saving the **imgData** into database and later using it like:
`NSString *str = [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];
 NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 cell.profileImg.image = image;`
 But after setting NSData to image image returns nil. whereas NSString and NSData is not null.

Comment: Can you help with the second option? I just updated the question.

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/5308188/1106035 to save image in database and will get image in NSData which can be used like this UIImage  *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgDataObtainedFromDataBase];

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this method to get Image :

```
 - (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
                             didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
    {
    if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
        NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

      UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:contactImageData];
    }

    [_addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
NSData *imagedata = (__bridge NSData *)(ABPersonCopyImageData(person));
UIImage  *img;
if(imagedata !=nil)
img = [UIImage imageWithData:contactImageData];
else  // assign it a temporary image.
img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TempImage"];

[contactInfoDict setObject:img forKey:@"image"];
```

After this :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"])];
    cell.profileImg.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting UIImage for key. So I think you do not need this code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"])];
cell.profileImg.image = image;
```

Just

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage*)[contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];
cell.profileImg.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Take `contactInfoDict`  as a `NSMutableDictionary` then Try the following code.

```
NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
[contactInfoDict setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:contactImageData]; forKey:@"image"]; 

// As its an Mutable dictionary, it will save the Value for sure.
```

To get the Image again

```
cell.profileImg.image = ( UIImage *) [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];
```

**Update**

To get the image from Address Book directly by its record id

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( ); 
NSNumber *recordId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[record_str integerValue]];
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,recordId.integerValue);
NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
cell.profileImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:contactImageData];
```

Comment: Did you take **NSMutableDictionary** ? What the Crashlog Shows? Can you post a screenshot of it? in Which line its Crashing?

Comment: `cell.profileImg.image = ( UIImage *) [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];`

Comment: `-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fecf1fbf340
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fecf1fbf340'`

Comment: Prasad HotaSiba: Can you help with the second option? I just updated the question.

Comment: You are storing the ContactDict to Sqlite? You should Mention this in the Question. From the log it seems you are getting the String that is the reason its crashing. **Why you saving image to Sqlite?** you just save the Record id & whenever required get the Image from addressbook by the record id.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit. I mean how to do it?

Comment: First you need to get the RecordID for that Contact. Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055438/how-to-get-abrecordref-from-abrecordid   When you need to display the Image, use the same record id and get the Image from Addressbook.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here you create a `UIImage` from `CGImage` and store it in a `NSDictionary`:

```
NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
UIImage  *img = [UIImage imageWithData:contactImageData];
NSLog(@"%@",img); //returns like '<UIImage: 0x7fc740460260>'
[contactInfoDict setObject:img forKey:@"image"];
```

But here you treat a `UIImage` object as a `CGImage` (remember, you already created a `UIImage`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"])];
cell.profileImg.image = image;
```

Try this instead:

```
cell.profileImg.image = [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];
```

Comment: Which line does it crash at? can you post code where you create a `contactInfoDict` object? Is it a `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: `cell.profileImg.image = [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];` this one.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: `-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fecf1fbf340
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fecf1fbf340'`

Comment: Is `contactInfoDict` a `strong` property?

Comment: This looks like the reason. Make sure your `contactInfoDict` is not released before you try to get an image out of it.

Comment: but I'm using contactInfoDict to store into SQLlite. and later fetching the data from database and store it into contactInfoDict again and retrieving the image.

Comment: Can you help with the second option? I just updated the question.

Comment: You are storing the ContactDict to Sqlite? You should Mention this in the Question because, from the log it seems you are getting the String that is the reason its crashing while assigning to imageview. **Why you saving image to Sqlite?** you just save the Record id & whenever required get the Image from addressbook by the recordid.

Comment: You are putting a `UIImage` object into `contactInfoDict` for "image" key, so why do you expect that to get a `NSString` instead of `UIImage`? Your "fetching" should look like `cell.profileImg.image = [contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"image"];`